# Console application for bank management

Tags: beginner, c, programming-challenge

I am new to C. I tried to make a bank management console application. I want some one to review it for advice to enhance and develop my coding skills.

This is what the program does with the inputs:

- `1` add an account
- `2` search for a specific account
- `3` modify a specific account
- `4` delete a specific account

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//part of declaration of the types      

typedef struct date
{
  int j,m,a;//j:day/m:month/a:year
}date;

typedef struct cus //cus:client
{
    char  name[50],prenom[50],adr[50],tel[50];//adr: adresse/prenom:name/name:family name
    int f;// f:ID
    date datec;//date:date of birth

}cus;

typedef struct
{
  int ic,solde;//ic:ID_Client/solde:how much money in the account
  char  tc;//tc:Type_Compte
  bool b;//b:Bloqed or opened
}account;

cus t[10];//cus is for costumer
account v[10];

//part of the functions or procedures
       //part of search functions and procedures

int msearchclient()
{
    cus cuss;
    int d=32,k,*a,p;
    printf("enter the ID of the costumer:");
    scanf("%d" ,&cuss.f);
     for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
      {
        if(cuss.f==t[i].f)
         {
          k=1;
          printf("\n");
          printf("\t\tFOUND\n\n");
          a=&t[i].f;
          p=*a;
         }
      }

      if(k!=1)
        printf("\t\tNOT FOUND\n\n");

    return p;

}

void mshowclient()
{
    int d=32,a=msearchclient();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
         {
          if(a==t[i].f)
           {
          printf("|FULL Name\t\t|ID\t\t|Adresse\t\t|Telphone Number\t\t|Date of Birth\n");
          printf("|%s%c%s \t\t|%d\t\t|%s\t\t|%s\t\t|%d/%d/%d\n" ,t[i].name,d,t[i].prenom,t[i].f,t[i].adr,t[i].tel,t[i].datec.j,t[i].datec.m,t[i].datec.a);

          }
         }
}


int msearchaccount()
{
    account accountt;
    int k,*a,p;

    printf("enter the ID of account:");
    scanf("%d" ,&accountt.ic);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
         if(accountt.ic==v[i].ic)
         {
             k=1;
             printf("\n");
             printf("\t\tFOUND\n\n");
             a=&v[i].ic;
             p=*a;

         }
    }
    if(k!=1)
        printf("\t\tNOT FOUND\n\n");

    return p;
}


void mshowaccount()
{
    int a=msearchaccount();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
      {
         if(a==v[i].ic)
         {
            printf("|Account ID\t\t|Type of account\t\t|Balance\t\t|Account Opened(1) or closed(0)\n");
            printf("|%d\t\t|%c\t\t|%d\t\t|%d\n" ,v[i].ic,v[i].tc,v[i].solde,v[i].b);
         }
      }
}

void msearch()
{

  int x;
  printf("\n\n");
  printf("Do you want search :\n=>>(1)the client \n=>>(2)the account \n=>>(3)Account and client informations \n=>>(4)Back \n=>>");
  scanf("%d" ,&x);
  switch (x)
  {

  case 1:
    {

        msearchclient();

    }break;

   case 2:
       {
           msearchaccount();

       }break;

   case 3:
    {
        mshowclient();
        mshowaccount();
    }break;

   case 4:
    {
        MENU();
    }break;

   default :{printf("enter another number please\n");msearch();}
  }

}


       //part of delete function

void mdelete()
{

  account accountt;
  cus cuss;
  int x;
  printf("\n\n");
  printf("Do you want delete :\n=>>the client (1)\n=>>the account (2)\n=>>Back (3)\n=>>");
  scanf("%d" ,&x);
  switch (x)
  {

  case 1:
    {

         printf("enter the id of the client:");
         scanf("%d" ,&cuss.f);
         int k;

      for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
         {
          if(cuss.f==t[i].f)

            {

            t[i].name[50]=NULL;
            t[i].prenom[50]=NULL;
            t[i].datec.a=NULL;
            t[i].datec.j=NULL;
            t[i].datec.m=NULL;
            t[i].adr[50]=NULL;
            t[i].tel[50]=NULL;
            k=1;
            }
          }
          int i,d=32;
      if(k==1)
        printf("GOOD we deleted it");


    }break;

   case 2:
       {
            printf("enter the id of the account:");
            scanf("%d" ,&accountt.ic);
            int k;

      for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
         {
          if(accountt.ic==v[i].ic)

            {
            v[i].ic=NULL;
            v[i].solde=NULL;
            v[i].tc=NULL;
            v[i].b=NULL;
            k=1;
            }
          }
     if(k==1)
        printf("GOOD we deleted it");

       }break;
    case 3:
    {

        MENU();
    }
   default :{printf("enter another number please\n");mdelete();}
  }



}




     //part of modify functions and prosedures


void mmmenuodify()
{
    int n;
    account accountt;
    printf("\n");
    printf("what do you want to modify in the account:\n");
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("1- the amount of money\n");
    printf("2- the type of the account\n");
    printf("3- the id of account\n");
    printf("4- Blocking the account\n");
    printf("5- Extract the money\n");
    printf("6- Deposite the money\n");
    printf("7- Back\n");
    printf("\n=>>");

    scanf("%d",&n);

    switch (n)
    {
        case 1:
          {
            printf("enter the new amount of money");
            scanf("%d" ,&accountt.solde);


            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
             {
                if(msearchaccount()==v[i].ic)
                   {
                    v[i].solde=accountt.solde;
                    msearchaccount();
                   }

             }
             msearchaccount();
          }break;

        case 2:
          {
            printf("enter the new type:");
            scanf("%c" ,&accountt.tc);

            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
              {
                if(msearchaccount()==v[i].ic)
                   v[i].tc=accountt.tc;
              }
          }break;

        case 3:
          {
             printf("enter the new id of account:");
             scanf("%d" ,&accountt.ic);

             for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
              {
               if(msearchaccount()==v[i].ic)
                 v[i].ic=accountt.ic;
              }
          }break;

        case 4:
            {
                int n;
                printf("enter the number:\n=>>(0) for blocking the account\n=>>(1) for opening he account\n=>>");
                scanf("%d" ,&n);
                if(n==0)
                {

                    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                       {
                         if(msearchaccount()==v[i].ic)
                            v[i].b=0;
                       }
                }


                else if(n==1)
                {

                    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                       {
                         if(msearchaccount()==v[i].ic)
                            v[i].b=1;
                       }
                }

            }

        case 5:
          {
             printf("enter how much do you want to take:");
             scanf("%d" ,&accountt.solde);

             for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
              {
               if(msearchaccount()==v[i].ic)
                 {
                 if(v[i].solde>0)
                    v[i].solde=v[i].solde-accountt.solde;
                 else
                 {
                     printf("you can't take money because you don't have money in the account");
                     break;
                 }
                 }

              }

          }break;

        case 6:
          {
               printf("enter how much do you want to deposite:");
             scanf("%d" ,&accountt.solde);

             for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
              {
               if(msearchaccount()==v[i].ic)
                 v[i].solde=v[i].solde+accountt.solde;
              }

          }break;

        case 7:
          {
               printf(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n");
               MENU();
          }break;

        default: {printf("enter new number");mmmenuodify();}
    }

}

void mmodify()
{
    mmmenuodify();

}

    //part of create function

void mcreate()
{
     int x;
     printf("\n");
     printf("how many costumers you want to add:");
     scanf("%d" ,&x);

     //FILE *pr=fopen("tahiro.txt" ,"w+");

            for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
              {

                printf("enter the full name:" );
                scanf("%s %s" ,&t[i].prenom,&t[i].name);//when you enter the full name you have to make space between the name and family name and in the same family name no spaces

                printf("enter thier ID:");
                scanf("%d" ,&t[i].f);



                printf("enter the date of birth:");
                scanf("%d/%d/%d" ,&t[i].datec.j,&t[i].datec.m,&t[i].datec.a);

                printf("enter the telephone number:");
                scanf("%d" ,&t[i].tel);

                printf("enter Adresse please:");
                scanf("%s" ,&t[i].adr);

                printf("\n\n");
                printf("Now for the account informations");
                printf("\n\n");

                printf("enter the account ID please:");
                scanf("%d" ,&v[i].ic);

                int a=2020-t[i].datec.a;


                if(a>=18)
                {
                    printf("------------------------------\n");
                    printf("Enter the type of the account:\n=>>'P' for particular account\n=>>'C' for commercial\n");


                    getchar();
                    scanf("%c",&v[i].tc);

                    printf("------------------------------\n");
                }
                else if(a>0&&a<18)
                    v[i].tc='M';


               printf("enter the amount of money:");
                scanf("%d" ,&v[i].solde);

                printf("Block or Not:");
                scanf("%d" ,&v[i].b);

                //fprintf(pr,"%s\t\t%s\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%s\t\t%d/%d/%d\t\t%c\n" ,t[i].name,t[i].prenom,t[i].f,t[i].tel,t[i].adr,t[i].datec.j,t[i].datec.m,t[i].datec.a,v[i].tc);
                if(x>1)
                {
                    printf("do you want to continue(Y/N):\n=>>");
                    if(getchar()=='N'||getchar()=='n')
                       break;
                }



                printf("\n\n");
              }

              //fclose(pr);
}

     //part of menu function


void MENU()
{
    int n;
    printf("\t\tHELLO AND WELCOME");
    printf("\n\n\n");

    printf("1-Add an account\n");
    printf("2-Find an account\n");
    printf("3-Modify an account\n");
    printf("4-Delete an account\n");
    printf("\n\n\n");
    printf("chosse the number for the service:");
    scanf("%d" ,&n);
    printf("\n");
    switch (n)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                printf(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n");
                mcreate();
                printf("\n\n\n");
                printf(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n");
                MENU();
            }break;

            case 2:
            {
                printf(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n");
                msearch();
                printf("\n\n\n");
                printf(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n");
                MENU();
            }break;

            case 3:
            {
                printf(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n");
                mmodify();
                printf("\n\n\n");
                printf(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n");
                MENU();
            }break;

            case 4:
            {
                printf(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n");
                mdelete();
                printf("\n\n\n");
                printf(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n");
                MENU();
            }break;
        }
}


   //main part

void main()
{
    system("color 0A");
    MENU();
}
```

Comment: _@Taher Rezzag_ Unfortunately your code [doesn't even compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/027c01be31d24bde). Fix that first please before coming back here to ask about improvements. (BTW use the word _customer_ please, a [_costumer_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Costumer) is something completely different)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  Are you compiling with C++ or C?  I get 
"warning: implicit declaration of function 'MENU' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]", you got "error: 'MENU' was not declared in this scope", yet with  file   named "main.cpp", I am suspicious the of what compiler was used.

Comment: @chux As you can clearly see at the link, I was compiling with the following command: `gcc main.cpp` without any further specific options. The compiler used was `gcc`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm using CLion on top of Visual Studio 2019 and it doesn't compile. Among other error messages some of the scanfs are using a numeric format to read strings.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I am unfamiliar with "CLion on top of Visual Studio 2019".  Does that constitute a C compilation?  My C compilation gave many warnings, yet no errors.  What error did you receive?  "scanfs are using a numeric format to read strings." is certainly bad beginner code, yet is not an _error_, but UB.  Of course many do compile with warnings treated as errors.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As gcc with `gcc main.cpp` can compile that code as C++ (something that was not clear to me as I rarely use gcc with *.cpp files - but researched it now), it looks like the error you see is a C++ one so [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/237741/console-application-for-bank-management/237747#comment466273_237741) does not match the C tag of the post.  When compiling with C, OP's code can compile without warnings.  Unfortunately even with modest warning levels, many warnings.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It is primarily the Visual Studio C compiler, Jet Brains CLion provides an alternate IDE and uses CMake rather than Visual Studio Project files. CLion can also be used with Clang and gcc.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Unfortunately I can't tell coliru to use `main.c` instead of `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> or advice to enhance and develop my coding skills.

**Enable all warnings**

I received many with "gcc -std=c11 -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -c -fmessage-length=0 ".  See list below.

Save time and let the automatic checking of a good well enabled compiler provide you feedback.

**Weak input**

All input is through `scanf()`.  That consistency is *good*, yet `scanf()` is very difficult to use and handle unexpected input.   Use `fgets()` to read a *line* of user input into a *string*.  Then parse the *string*.

**Classic missing space with %c**

Code's usage of `scanf()` leaves the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or `'\n'` in `stdin`.  The `"%c"` in `scanf("%c", &accountt.tc);`, unlike `"%s" and "%d"`, does not consume and toss  leading white space.  When  case 2 is not used first, `scanf("%c"` will read a `'\n'`.

```
  // scanf("%c", &accountt.tc);
  scanf(" %c", &accountt.tc);
```

**Check return values of input**

The return value of `scanf()` is not checked.

**Cope with names better**

Real names can have spaces in the first name.  Real names can have spaces in the last name.  Real names can exceed 49 letters.

**Use width limits with %s**

Do not use `%s` without a width. `%s` --> `%49s` for code's `name[50]`.

**Avoid (naked) magic numbers**

Example: Instead of `name[50]`

```
#define NAME_MAX_SIZE 50

char name[NAME_MAX_SIZE];
```

**Auto formatting**

Many coding environments have an *auto formatter*.  Post code is unnecessarily difficult to read.  Improve format with tools - do not waste time doing it manually.

**Spell checker**

Deposite --> Deposit

---

```
../test.c:34:7: warning: unused variable 'd' [-Wunused-variable]
   int d = 32, k, *a, p;
       ^
../test.c: In function 'msearch':
../test.c:132:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'MENU' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       MENU();
       ^~~~
../test.c: In function 'mdelete':
../test.c:168:25: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
           t[i].name[50] = NULL;
                         ^
../test.c:169:27: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
           t[i].prenom[50] = NULL;
                           ^
../test.c:170:24: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
           t[i].datec.a = NULL;
                        ^
../test.c:171:24: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
           t[i].datec.j = NULL;
                        ^
../test.c:172:24: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
           t[i].datec.m = NULL;
                        ^
../test.c:173:24: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
           t[i].adr[50] = NULL;
                        ^
../test.c:174:24: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
           t[i].tel[50] = NULL;
                        ^
../test.c:178:14: warning: unused variable 'd' [-Wunused-variable]
       int i, d = 32;
              ^
../test.c:178:11: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
       int i, d = 32;
           ^
../test.c:194:19: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
           v[i].ic = NULL;
                   ^
../test.c:195:22: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
           v[i].solde = NULL;
                      ^
../test.c:196:19: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
           v[i].tc = NULL;
                   ^
../test.c: In function 'mcreate':
../test.c:362:13: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[50]' [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%s %s", &t[i].prenom, &t[i].name); //when you enter the full name you have to make space between the name and family name and in the same family name no spaces
            ~^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
../test.c:362:16: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'char (*)[50]' [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%s %s", &t[i].prenom, &t[i].name); //when you enter the full name you have to make space between the name and family name and in the same family name no spaces
               ~^                 ~~~~~~~~~~
../test.c:371:13: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[50]' [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%d", &t[i].tel);
            ~^   ~~~~~~~~~
../test.c:374:13: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[50]' [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%s", &t[i].adr);
            ~^   ~~~~~~~~~
../test.c:401:13: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type '_Bool *' [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%d", &v[i].b);
            ~^   ~~~~~~~
../test.c: At top level:
../test.c:418:6: warning: conflicting types for 'MENU'
 void MENU() {
      ^~~~
../test.c:132:7: note: previous implicit declaration of 'MENU' was here
       MENU();
       ^~~~
../test.c:472:6: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain]
 void main() {
      ^~~~
../test.c: In function 'mdelete':
../test.c:208:7: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
       MENU();
       ^~~~~~
../test.c:210:5: note: here
     default: {
     ^~~~~~~
../test.c: In function 'mmmenuodify':
../test.c:275:13: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
     case 4: {
             ^
../test.c:298:5: note: here
     case 5: {
     ^~~~
```

Comment: There are 2 VTC, one of those may have been a DV.

Comment: thanks for everyone how gived me advices to enhance my coding skills it was nice to ask people like you .

Answer (score -2):

You are omitting to pass parameters to functions, that code will never compile.

For example:
The function `int msearchclient()`  use the array `t[i]` but you never pass it as an argument.

Comment: _"You are omitting to pass parameters to functions, that code will never compile."_ That's nonsense. `cus t[10];` is a global variable definition. Thus it would be accessible from any function body. Also don't answer _off-topic_ questions here please.

Comment: no it would the function use the array t[10] with out declaring the parameters because i did't work with files to store data so i declared the array t[10] as const so i can work with it when i ever i want

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ He doesn't have enough points to see VTC. The answer should be `don't use global variables` rather than it won't compile.